# Synergy v1.4.15 Failing to work on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

Could someone please advise. I am running Synergy v1.4.15 on a Windows 8.1 computer as server, running as Admin but I keep getting the follow error. Has anyone resolved it.

I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it as Admin and allowed Synergy to create network firewall exception.

ERROR: cannot read configuration "C:/Users/[UserName]/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.Uh7160": read error: line 20: alias "SECOND-PC" is already used
synergys.exe: no configuration available
ERROR: failed to launch, error: process immediately stopped

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to connect a Windows 8 (as server) with a Windows 7 (as client) through synergy v1.3.1. After having some troubles with the last version, 1.5, I decided to download the version 1.3.1 and it is working perfect.

Here you have the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy2/

This is the configuration I have used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OixCfusCiuA